# Best Method Password Protected Pages

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, session, passwords

so im doing a favor for a sporting league im apart of and have put together and reasonably professional looking website.

Ive set this up so that someone from the league can post news, update the ladder, fixture etc etc.

However im unsure about the best way to implement a login area to protect these pages that allow a user to upload files/change mysql table data. A simple google search has given me too many options to sift through to actually determine whats suitable and what is current, many of the results are from multiple years ago.

I dont need a code written out for me i just need an idea of what is the best practice at the moment for a simple log in that protects 5 or 6 pages with maybe 3 or 4 different user/pass combinations. The server is running PHP5.4 and i numerous linux hosted MySQL databases available.

My questions are, should i be using hashes? which ones? MD5? thats gotta be old by now. Sessions? .htaccess? a poke in a good direction as of 2014 would be fantastic. Keep in mind, the chance of anyone maliciously attacking this website is very low imo, and the cost of data loss would be non existent.

Comment: .htaccess protecting the directory should be satisfactory for the limited purposes you describe

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a similar style of password encryption to the following:

```
$[password_var] = base64_encode(pack('H*',sha1($[password_var])));
```

You will also want to make sure you protect yourself from SQL injection, for best practice emplploy the use of PDO - a quick read can be found [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) on tutsplus.

Answer (score 0):

SHA-2 and Blowfish are good methods, for encryption. The most important thing is, encrypting into Blowfish or SHA-2 is quite slow which makes bruteforcing take a lot of time.

An example for blowfish:

```
//Generating salt, must be 22 characters or more for blowfish. You can make a function for this.
$some_str = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$base_64str = base64_encode($some_str);
$modified_base64 = str_replace('+', '.', $base_64str);
$salt = substr($modified_base64, 0, 22);

//Format String i.e. which method we will be using and how many times the password will be encrypted.
$format_str = "$2y$10$"; // 2y for Blowfish and 10 times.

$fs = $format_str . $salt;
$hased_pass = crypt($password, $fs);
```

and Also use session as well for remembering the user.